# C++ vector with fixed capacity after initialization

Tags: c++, vector

I need a C++ container with the following requirements:

- The container can store non-copyable AND non-movable objects in continuous memory. For `std::vector` the object has to be either copyable or movable.
- The `capacity` of the container is known during the construction at run-time, and fixed until destruction. All the needed memory space is allocated during the construction. For `boost::static_vector` the capacity is known at compile time.
- The size of the container can increase over time when `emplace_back` more element in the container, but should never exceeds `capacity`.
- Since the object is not copyable or movable, reallocation is not allowed.

It appears that neither STL nor BOOST has the container type I need. I have also searched in this side extensively but did not find an answer. So I have implemented one.

```cpp
#include <memory>

template<class T>
class FixedCapacityVector {
private:
    using StorageType = std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>;
    static_assert(sizeof(StorageType) == sizeof(T));
public:
    FixedCapacityVector(FixedCapacityVector const&) = delete;
    FixedCapacityVector& operator=(FixedCapacityVector const&) = delete;
    FixedCapacityVector(size_t capacity = 0):
        capacity_{ capacity },
        data_{ std::make_unique<StorageType[]>(capacity) }
    { }
    ~FixedCapacityVector()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size_; i++)
            reinterpret_cast<T&>(data_[i]).~T();
    }
    template<class... Args>
    T& emplace_back(Args&&... args) 
    {
        if (size_ == capacity_)
            throw std::bad_alloc{};
        new (&data_[size_]) T{ std::forward<Args>(args)... };
        return reinterpret_cast<T&>(data_[size_++]);
    }
    T& operator[](size_t i) 
    { return reinterpret_cast<T&>(data_[i]); }
    T const& operator[](size_t i) const 
    { return reinterpret_cast<T const&>(data_[i]); }
    size_t size() const { return size_; }
    size_t capacity() const { return capacity_; }
    T* data() { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(data_.get()); }
    T const* data() const { return reinterpret_cast<T const*>(data_.get()); }
private:
    size_t const capacity_;
    std::unique_ptr<StorageType[]> const data_;
    size_t size_{ 0 };
};
```

My questions are:

- Why would I do this by hand? I could not find a standard container. Or maybe I did not look at the right place? Or because what I am trying to do is not conventional?
- Is the hand-written container correct implemented? How about the exception safety, memory safety, etc.?

Comment: The "For such a commonly needed container type..." is incorrect.  Can your non-copyable-and-non-movable object be stored in a `std::shared_ptr`, and then the `std::shared_ptr` be stored in a `std::vector`?

Comment: @Eljay Thanks for the comment. The objects then are not in continuous memory. Actually that's what the program is doing now (using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr>`). Maybe I should not say "such a commonly needed container type".

Comment: Do the non-copyable-and-non-movable objects need to be in continuous memory?

Comment: Why not simply wrap a `std::vector` that is resized to the maximum needed, and keep track of how many elements are actually in use?   If that vector is a private member of your class, you can ensure it is never resized after initialisation, whatever the user of your class does.    After all, even if the user asks your class to `emplace_back()` something, your class (or the implementation of its member functions) does not need to turn that into calls of the vector's `emplace_back()`.

Comment: @Peter Actually that's the first thing I have thought about. But ``std::vector<T>`` will not compile if ``T`` is both not copyable and not movable.

Comment: @TonyXiang - if using C++ before C++11 that is true (the element must be copy assignable and copy constructible).For C++11 and later, the element is only required to be Erasable (which essentially means `p->~T()` is valid if `p` is a pointer to a non-destructed `T`).   However, you need to be careful in choice of operations on the vector, since some member functions of `std::vector` have stricter requirements  (e.g. [from memory] vector's `emplace()` requires elements to be Move Assignable, Move Insertable, and Emplace Constructible - as distinct from copy assignable and copy constructible).

Comment: @Peter I have just tried instantiating ``std::vector<T>`` for non-copyable-non-movable ``T``. As you said, the instantiation itself can be compiled. However, non of the method can be used to add element to the vector. I thought ``emplace_back`` could be used since it does not require copy or move action if no reallocation is needed. But the compiler still complains of deleted copy constructor. Do you have any idea how to add element to the vector in this case?

Comment: Obviously, if a container can be resized after construction, then any function that add item might need to copy or move existing items

Comment: While your code seems correct, I think it should be possible (and safer) to write it without that much casts.

Answer (score 1):

It probably does not answer the question completely but it seems like *fixed_capacity_vector* might be added into future C++ standard(s) according to the following paper:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0843r1.html

## Introduction

This paper proposes a modernized version of boost::container::static_vector [1]. That is, a dynamically-resizable vector with compile-time fixed capacity and contiguous embedded storage in which the elements are stored within the vector object itself.

Its API closely resembles that of std::vector. It is a contiguous container with O(1) insertion and removal of elements at the end (non-amortized) and worst case O(size()) insertion and removal otherwise. Like std::vector, the elements are initialized on insertion and destroyed on removal. For trivial value_types, the vector is fully usable inside constexpr functions.

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

> Why would I do this by hand? I could not find a standard container. Or maybe I did not look at the right place? Or because what I am trying to do is not conventional?

This is not conventional. By convention, something that is *MoveConstructible* is also *MoveAssignable*

> Is the hand-written container correct implemented? How about the exception safety, memory safety, etc.?

`data` is problematic. Callers are likely to assume that they can increment that pointer to get at other elements, but that is strictly undefined. You don't actually have an array of `T`. The standard requires implementation-defined magic in `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit old post and not proposing exact requirements but, we open-sourced the implementation of the `FixedCapacityVector` used in production code of my company since years, available [here](https://github.com/AmadeusITGroup/amc). Capacity should be a compile-time constant.

It requires a C++11 compiler but API is in accordance with C++17's `std::vector`.